# Reference for Riemann–Zariski space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory

I am currently studying an article of Koji SEKIGUCHI "[Ringed Spaces of Valuation Rings and Projective Limits of Schemes](https://doi.org/10.3836/tjm/1270128992)", and in the last paragraph the author proves that the Riemann–Zariski space is isomorphic to projective limit of some family of proper integral schemes.

I think the result that the author try to prove is classic but the article is written in the modern language of sheaves.

So I have two questions :

1. For those who are familiar with this result, the definition that I know of projective limit is used for inverse system but I think this case, the author means the general definition of limit of a functor. Is this true ?
2. The study of this article with other of Prüfer helps me a lot to practice what i learn in scheme theory but  I don't understand the motivation for this space, I know it has something to do with singularity and birational geometry. Can you recommend me a book or article that talk about that, if possible in language of sheaves and ringed spaces?